# RAM Disappeared On Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome, memory, ram, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm on Developer Mode on a 4GB RAM Chromebook and randomly in the last month I've started hitting the RAM limits. I've no idea why. I used to be able to freely browse what I now have to make note of as 'high RAM sites'. I had around 40 sites open at once, including a YouTube video normally playing music or whatever, various social media sites such as Twitter and Facebook, Google Drive, a document or two, and *many* StackOverflow sites (I'm a bad python coder so I have to look everything up.
As well as this I was running around 10-15 extensions. I could even run the occasional web game if I felt like it.
And it was all fine, I never had problems.

However since I went into Developer mode around a month ago, and started dabbling in Crouton (now entirely useless since ChromeOS 69, so I've deleted the chroot which didn't solve the problem), I've constantly been hitting the RAM buffer. Since then, I've had to install a memory monitor extension, Extension Manager, and The Great Suspender and have 1-2 unsuspended tabs at once. Playing YouTube videos occasionally crashes, even when it's the only unsuspended tab.

I asked about this on the Google Products help forum, and they told me to try browsing as I did on Guest Mode, which worked fine and I could run every site as I wished, and as a result of this information, I now have to code on Repl.it in Guest Mode. Then under their advice I disabled all extensions, but it made no difference to the RAM usage. They then suggested I did a browser reset, which I did and made no difference at all. After responding that both of the suggested ideas didn't work, they said to look elsewhere because they only supported Stable Mode Chromebooks. And now I'm here.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks. I really don't want to do another factory reset because of the amount of time restoring my Chrome://Flags and Tampermonkey settings and re-downloading all the Linux apps on Crostini.

Comment: Oh is it? Sorry. What tags should I have given it?

Comment: @John: I'm guessing that maybe he didn't like your first 3 tags, and wanted you to only have picked chrome-os and chromebook tags!?

Comment: The 'moderator(very senior member)' who chastised a bit about your post being 'off-topic' was a slight bit out-of-line, in my opinion.  My objection is that (1) he wasn't clear WHY he thought it 'off-topic', but then came by later and deleted his initial comment.  Since you are a very new contributor, I get why he was trying to steer you, but I don't like his approach. Cheers...

Comment: I really LIKE your post...it helps us other Chromebook owners understand what other owners are experiencing.  And, more importantly, it allows you to (hopefully) get input from other like-minded folks.  Anyway...welcome to this 'forum'...it's one of the very best forums I've ever been a member of.  Cheers...

Comment: What does "free" show in "crosh"? Is it somehow possible that you have disabled "zram"?

Answer (score -1):

If it were me, I'd endure that extra pain, and DO the factory reset, on the chance that it might make the symptom go away.  Then, you'd know for sure whether it's a true hardware issue, or just some weird software interaction.

EDIT:  Oh, and you might consider nuking your Crouton setup (if you haven't), now that crostini is available.  Seems to me that that would radically simplify your whole configuration.

Comment: Thanks for all the help you've offered, how exactly should I go about nuking the crouton? I've deleted the chroot, but it hasn't fully deleted the entire structure of crouton I'm assuming. I probably will go for a factory reset soon, for now though, I've enabled some of the chrome flags and I'm just about managing. Thanks.

Comment: My thought was that you would do what Chrome-OS calls 'recovery'.  While it sounds 'severe', once you read thru the steps (and follow warnings about backup any important data you might have on the Chromebook), it is quite straightforward.  Read the details here:  https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595   It's gonna put the chromebook back to way it was the day you bought it (no accounts yet on the computer), and then you'll re-apply all the os-updates, and log in the first time, etc etc.

Comment: Also, I think (but not absolutely sure) your cloud-acct info KNOWS most all the stuff you had installed and offers to install them, so you don't have to REMEMBER them all).  I DO know that that's how Android does it, when you do 'recovery' of an Android tablet).  If it DOESN'T offer/suggest the 'Crostini' install, just manually select that one.  Again, (hopefully) I would expect it would remember of all your Crostini-dependent apps, and then offer to re-install them. But, again, this is only 'educated guess', since Crostini didn't exist back when I once DID do a 'recovery' on my Chromebook.

Comment: So, just for kicks, I took my own advice, and did a 'recovery' of my Chromebook today.  I created the USB-recovery device on my Win-10 laptop, and then followed the procedure for the Chromebook-side.  Only clarification from what I said earlier, is that it doesn't even ask...it just went 'poof' after I logged in, and all my regular apps were there!  The one I had to do manually, was 'Crossover' (for win-32 apps), and then it went 'poof' again, and installed the 5 or 6 Windows-apps that it remembered that I had.

Comment: Also, I had to EXPLICITLY go see what OS updates were avail...just the one, from 69.x to 70.x.  Pretty slick overall! (And not too scary.)  Cheers...